# Does function have transitivity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, periodic-functions

When I was solving a simple cycle problem, we assumed a function's symmetry about $x=a$ and $x=b$ and I tried to solve the function's cycle.

It seems very simple, and indeed it is. It's my process going about solving it. Because the function is symmetrical about $x=a$ and $x=b$.

So we have:

$$f(x-a)=f(x+a)\quad f(x-b)=f(x+b) \tag1$$

We let $x-a=t$, and then we can get:

$$f(t)=f(t+2a)\quad f(t)=f(t+2b)\tag2$$

Using $x$ to replace $t$, we get:

$$f(x)=f(x+2a)\quad f(x)=f(x+2b)\tag3$$

So we can let:

$$f(x+2a)=f(x+2b)\tag4$$

To get $f(x)=f(x+2(b-a))$. My question is why is formula $(4)$ valid? Does function have transitivity?

If we have $f(x),g(x),h(x)$,and $f(x)=g(x), g(x)=h(x)$, can we get $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: It's not that functions are transitive, it's that *equality* is transitive. If $A=B$ and $B=C$, then $A=C$.

Comment: Ok,thanks so much.it"s real a idiot question.

Comment: And thanks your edit work.@Andrew Li